# Alfresco 5.2 high CPU utilization & application slow performance

Tags: linux, performance, tomcat, jvm, alfresco

Recently we have upgraded alfresco to 5.2.G with Solar4 , Tomcat Version 7.0.78 ,java version "1.8.0_111" **environment** -- RHEL -7 ,Virtual machine , 32 core CPU ,32 GB RAM application is started without errors but with in 2 -3 hours application performance is slow & getting high CPU utilization.

Can anyone suggest what are basic tuning parameters need to change in OS & JVM & Alfresco & solar LEVEL, below are the JVM arguments add in tomcat:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms24576m -Xmx24576m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
  -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+UseParNewGC
  -XX:ParallelGCThreads=6 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
  -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dalfresco.home=/opt/new/alfresco -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
  -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m"
```

& alfresco-global.properties (line breaks added for readability) :

```
cifs.serverName=?
system.thumbnail.generate=false
system.enableTimestampPropagation=false
system.workflow.engine.activiti.enabled=false
sync.mode=OFF,system.workflow.engine.jbpm.enabled=false
removed-index.recovery.mode=FULL
```

Comment: Can you share some the log snippet where the errors are shown during startup ?

Comment: Hi there is no Errors in Startup , Issue is identified there is bug in alfresco 5.2  https://github.com/keensoft/alf-21970-repo  after install the recommended JAR file now CPU utilization is normal state .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Keep in mind that when checking CPU for multi-core CPU's using 'top' command, it shows the combined CPU usage over all the cores. [To show individual cores](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146085/top-command-on-multi-core-processor) press '1'.

I also applied the patch suggested above but it didnt show much difference (also there is [an issue with that patch for Alfresco 5.2.g](https://github.com/keensoft/alf-21970-repo/issues/1)).

I then tried [re-indexing](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr-reindex.html) all my content which seemed to speed up things a lot.

There is still a lot of usage but only during working hours. Once everyone goes home, it returns back to almost 0% usage

Another thing that really slowed my Alfresco response was a corrupted meta-data database. After I restored a backup, it performed much faster.

I also [disabled a lot of unnecessary features](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/maincomponents-disable.html) including [generation of thumbnails](https://www.tsgrp.com/2016/11/17/avoiding-alfresco-performance-problems-from-day-1-keeping-my-ecm-healthy/)

Comment: Thanks issue got resolved on the same day after bug fix applied